# debugging - random error when running the application

Tags: debugging, windbg

Sometimes I run my application, it will show [not responding] and be forced to close. I captured a Dump file and open it in WinDbg. Below is the information I get:

```
Loading unloaded module list
.
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(dd4.1dc): Wake debugger - code 80000007 (first/second chance not available)
eax=00000000 ebx=0018cdb0 ecx=0000000a edx=00000000 esi=00000002 edi=00000000
eip=7708015d esp=0018cd60 ebp=0018cdfc iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x15:
7708015d 83c404          add     esp,4
```

With command ".ecxr"

```
0.000 > .ecxr
eax=00000000 ebx=0018cdb0 ecx=0000000a edx=00000000 esi=00000002 edi=00000000
eip=7708015d esp=0018cd60 ebp=0018cdfc iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x15:
7708015d 83c404          add     esp,4
```

With command "!analyze -v"

0:000> !analyze -v

---

```
***************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for msvbvm60.dll - 
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for AppName.exe
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for msjava.dll - 

FAULTING_IP: 
+0
00000000 ??              ???

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 00000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000007 (Wake debugger)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

BUGCHECK_STR:  80000007

PROCESS_NAME:  AppName.exe

OVERLAPPED_MODULE: Address regions for 'msjtes40' and 'msadox.dll' overlap

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000007 - {Kernel Debugger Awakened}  the system debugger was awakened by an interrupt.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000007 (2147483655) - Operation aborted

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  AppName.exe

DERIVED_WAIT_CHAIN:  

Dl Eid Cid     WaitType
-- --- ------- --------------------------
   0   dd4.1dc Handle                 

WAIT_CHAIN_COMMAND:  ~0s;k;;

BLOCKING_THREAD:  000001dc

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_HungIn_ExceptionHandler

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_HANG_HungIn_ExceptionHandler

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 767615e9 to 7708015d

FAULTING_THREAD:  00000000

STACK_TEXT:  
0018cd60 767615e9 00000002 0018cdb0 00000001 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x15
0018cdfc 76361a2c 0018cdb0 0018ce24 00000000 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x100
0018ce44 76364220 00000002 7efde000 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation+0xe0
0018ce60 763880c4 00000002 0018ce94 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18
0018cecc 76387f83 0018cfa4 00000001 00000001 kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal+0x186
0018cee0 76387878 0018cfa4 00000001 0018cf7c kernel32!WerpReportFault+0x70
0018cef0 763877f7 0018cfa4 00000001 80471969 kernel32!BasepReportFault+0x20
0018cf7c 7295fa2e 00000000 72a2bd04 0018cfac kernel32!UnhandledExceptionFilter+0x1af
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0018ff80 00405b66 004068b4 763633aa 7efde000 msvbvm60!Zombie_Release+0x10fd5
0018ff94 77099f72 7efde000 719353d4 00000000 AppName+0x5b66
0018ffd4 77099f45 00405b5c 7efde000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
0018ffec 00000000 00405b5c 7efde000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
msvbvm60!Zombie_Release+10fd5
7295fa2e c3              ret

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  8

SYMBOL_NAME:  msvbvm60!Zombie_Release+10fd5

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: msvbvm60

IMAGE_NAME:  msvbvm60.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a5bda6c

STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s ; kb

BUCKET_ID:  80000007_msvbvm60!Zombie_Release+10fd5

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_HungIn_ExceptionHandler_80000007_msvbvm60.dll!Zombie_Release

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/AppName_exe/8_0_0_0/52036491/unknown/0_0_0_0/bbbbbbb4/80000007/00000000.htm?Retriage=1

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Comment: msvbvm60 implies that this is a program made by Visual Basic, and I don't think Windbg can do any crash dump analyze for you.

Comment: Symbols for AppName might help in that it might show a function that you've written.

Comment: This is a VB6 application. Could you please tell me how can I findthe Symbols for my application?

Comment: [Following post](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/2007-04/msg00195.html) seems to be closely related to what you've posted. In short, your application AV'd and the postmortem debugger got stuck waiting to attach itself to your application. I would advise to try the posted recommendation *(AppVerifier)*